# VB.NET Bound Datagridview - Change font dynamically?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

**Introduction**

I have a datagridview that has its data populated by assigning a datatable to it early on in my code. The data shows up no problem. I am then trying to later go through and apply a back color and font to **only certain cells** so not all of them.

**What I have tried**

Now from doing some research this seems to be done through the styles property of each cell.  I have built a loop like so:

```
Dim strikethrough_style As New DataGridViewCellStyle

    strikethrough_style.Font = strikethrough_font
    strikethrough_style.BackColor = Color.Red

For row = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            For col = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(col).Style = strikethrough_style
            Next
Next
```

This should supposedly change *all* of my cells to have a red background and have a strikethrough font however none of the cells change when ran.

I can change the defaultcellstyle property like this:

```
DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle = strikethrough_style
```

*which does work for all cells,*

but like I said above, I want to ultimately only change certain rows, not all.  Is there something overriding my style? If so, how can I get around this?

**Update**

So oddly enough if I try:

```
DataGridView1.Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle = strikethrough_style
```

the column does apply the style; however, when I try:

```
DataGridView1.Rows(1).DefaultCellStyle = strikethrough_style
```

the row does not. Seems odd that I can apply a style to a column and not a row.

Comment: Loop thru all rows - regardless of whether the user ever scrolls to them - is inefficient.  Use the CellFormatting event to evaluate the condition and set the appropriate style there.

Comment: @Plutonix The problem is more so with why " DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(col).Style = strikethrough_style" doesn't work. I can and will write my code with the proper condition; however, regardless if I loop or go through my conditions or not, the same code would be referenced, so how do you suggest I solve that problem Plutonix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer after trying many things and wanted to share so nobody makes the same mistake that I did. Initially I had my styling code occuring right after my datagridview was bound:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = sql_server.execute_sql(sql_server_location, commands)

    Dim strikethrough_style As New DataGridViewCellStyle
    strikethrough_style.Font = New Font(DataGridView1.Font.Name, DataGridView1.Font.Size, FontStyle.Strikeout)

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells(1).Value = True Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle = strikethrough_style
        End If
    Next
```

**The problem with this is that the datagridview is taking too long to finish binding the data.**

The better approach is to do the styling **after** the data has been bound through the bind complete event:

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DataBindingComplete

    Dim strikethrough_style As New DataGridViewCellStyle
    strikethrough_style.Font = New Font(DataGridView1.Font.Name, DataGridView1.Font.Size, FontStyle.Strikeout)

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells(1).Value = True Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle = strikethrough_style
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim strikethrough_style As New DataGridViewCellStyle

    strikethrough_style.Font = New Font("Times New Roman", 16, FontStyle.Bold)
    strikethrough_style.BackColor = Color.Red

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Datagridview1.Rows
        For i = 0 To Datagridview1.Columns.Count - 1
            row.Cells(i).Style = strikethrough_style
        Next
    Next
```

It should work.

Comment: Please see my update in my question but I tried what you said and still nothing changed.